# How do I create a proper /etc/fstab file for my LFS partition?

Tags: ubuntu, fstab, lfs

I'm trying to create an appropriate /etc/fstab file for my LFS partition, as in LFS part 8.2.  How do I find out the file systems for my / mount-point and my swap mount point ( and )?  And how do I find out the type of my / mount-point?  I'm using a Ubuntu 17.04 host, and [this](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter08/fstab.html) is what I'm using as a model (pasted below).

```
cat > /etc/fstab << "EOF"
# Begin /etc/fstab

# file system  mount-point  type     options             dump  fsck
#                                                              order

/dev/<xxx>     /            <fff>    defaults            1     1
/dev/<yyy>     swap         swap     pri=1               0     0
proc           /proc        proc     nosuid,noexec,nodev 0     0
sysfs          /sys         sysfs    nosuid,noexec,nodev 0     0
devpts         /dev/pts     devpts   gid=5,mode=620      0     0
tmpfs          /run         tmpfs    defaults            0     0
devtmpfs       /dev         devtmpfs mode=0755,nosuid    0     0

# End /etc/fstab
EO
```

Comment: `blkid` is your friend! Also if you used archlinux, [genfstab](https://sources.archlinux.org/other/arch-install-scripts/) works in LFS (it's a simple bash script to generate a fstab).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per lfs book description:

> Replace `<xxx>`, `<yyy>`, and `<fff>` with the values appropriate for the
>   system, for example, sda2, sda5, and ext4.

**your root partition** described by:

```
/dev/<xxx>     /            <fff>    defaults            1     1
```

is the same partition you set up in chapter *"2.4. Creating a New Partition"*, and later mounted as your `$LFS` (by default `/mnt/lfs`). and as per book description it's something like `/dev/sda5`.

type of root partition (`<fff>` in fstab example) was set by you in chapter *"2.5. Creating a File System on the Partition"*. by default it is `ext4`.

if unsure, you can use `mount` command from your host. wihout any options it returns all mounted partitions, so you look for something like:

```
/dev/sda9 on /mnt/lfs type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
```

in my case it is device `/dev/sda9` and type is `ext4`, and that's what i put in my fstab for `<xxx>` and `<fff>`.

**swap partition** described by:

```
/dev/<yyy>     swap         swap     pri=1               0     0
```

was probably already on your ubuntu host, so you didn't set it up in chapter 2. but we can again look it up in already mounted partitions.
command `mount | grep swap` will show you only mounted swap partitions. and again, you take device name and substitute `<yyy>` for it :)

**rest** of the fstab file you leave as it is in the example, should work without any more changes.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with LFS.  But, the "mount" command does a good job of guessing what file system is on the partition.  Create a mount point for the partition, mount it, then run the mount command again.

```
# mkdir -p /mnt/hd
# mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/hd
# mount
```

The output of the last command should look something like this:

```
/dev/sda6        swap             swap        defaults         0   0
/dev/sda8        /                ext4        defaults         1   1
/dev/sda5        /mnt/old         ext4        defaults         1   2
/dev/sda7        /usr/src/        ext4        defaults         1   2
/dev/sda9        /var/log         ext4        defaults         1   2
/dev/sdb1        /home            ext4        defaults         1   2
```